# How to sum up the series of x + 1/x + 1/(x + 1/x) + 1/(x + 1/x + 1/(x + 1/x)) for some finite number of terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractions

I'm having trouble in coming up with a formula for this series:

$$S = x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x} + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x}} +\cfrac1{x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x} + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x + \cfrac1{x + \frac1x}} } + \cdots + a_n $$

How can I find $S$ ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Oh wait, finite number of terms. Then it is not the same question any longer!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I was too fast, this one actually says finite number of terms.

Comment: Please write your thoughts on the problem. Don't throw your problem on others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the function $f(x) = 1 + 1/x$ and then call it $n$ times

n=

1. $$f(x) = x+\frac 1 x$$
2. $$f(f(x)) = f(x) + \frac 1 {f(x)}$$
3. $$f(f(f(x))) = f(f(x)) + \frac 1 {f(f(x))}$$

etc.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it becomes very complex at large number of terms. Is there any formula for this series? Is it some well known series?

Comment: @SarthakJoshi: It's just to calculate $x+1/x$, store the value as $x$ and then put it back in over and over. Edited the answer to explain better.

Comment: So I need to recurse this function, even for very large parameters?

Comment: If you want to avoid deriving something more complicated it is an option.